# Warning C6386 (with array, not fstream)

Tags: c++, warnings

I was developing a Binary Class that uses three-state booleans to create an array with a clear delimiter (I didn't want to use vector because I'm stuborn and the code I am using will be transported to an Arduino, which I do not know whether or not it has the std library). Here is the enumeration I used:

`enum tribool { DELIM = -1, FALSE, TRUE };`

I was developing the Copy Constructor (or Move Constructor, I forgot the difference) of the Binary Class and on "triboolList[i] = (const tribool)copyBinary.triboolList[i];" I was getting Warning C6386.

I looked at Microsoft Learn and I still didn't understand the problem. I also looked at a stack overflow of this same issue; except the other person was having issues with this warning and std::fstream.

[Image of the code because I was having issues with text formatting (Sorry in advance)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6Fgc.png)

Edit: I should clarify that I haven't found any runtime issues with the Copy Constructor yet, it's just that the warning is concerning me a little bit

Edit 2: Nevermind, I found some issues. Here is a snippet of the error window: [Error snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idywp.png)

```
Binary::Binary(Binary& copyBinary, bool alias) { //I had to send a snippet because text formatting wasn't working
    if (alias) {
        triboolList = copyBinary.triboolList; //tribool List is defined as "tribool* triboolList;"
    }
    else {
        triboolList = new tribool[triLength(copyBinary.triboolList)];
        for (int i = 0; i < triLength(copyBinary.triboolList); i++) {
            triboolList[i] = (const tribool)copyBinary.triboolList[i];
        }
        triboolList[triLength(copyBinary.triboolList)] = DELIM;
    }
}
```

Comment: We can fix the formatting of code as text, we can't fix an image. Please copy and paste [mcve] into the question as text, someone will edit it to make formatting right. Also, include full warning message, as it includes important information.

Comment: fyi error & warning codes are almost useless when trying to understand the cause. You always have to read the full message. They are also not universal, but compiler specific. Anybody could write a compiler where `C6386` stands for "comparing values of different signdness" or whatever

Comment: Okay, I will place the code (even though I can't create the correct formatting)

Comment: and for your edits, you do not need to add "Edit:" for an edit. The question should be readable in its latest version as it is. If someone wants to see the edit history they can do so here: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77807120/revisions. Keeping the edit history in the question makes it harder to read rather than easier

Comment: Why not use `std::optional<bool>` it better describes intent, true/false or no value. And use `std::vector<std::optional<bool>>`  for your resizable array. Current C++ code hardly ever should have new/delete in it

Comment: [Why should i not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: "Three-state boolean" is nonsense. It seems you only use the third value to mark the end of an array, so why don't you store the size, or give up on being stubborn?

Comment: @PepijnKramer, I will be importing this code into a C++ IDE for Arduinos, and I'd like to minimize the use of external libraries in case the Arduino's IDE I'm using is different than Microsfot visual studio

Comment: Ok then using std::vector does make as much sense as `new`. But know the building blocks I use are propose part of external libraries but are part of the C++ standard library

Comment: what is the warning? you didnt tell us yet

Comment: The warning is in the Title: Warning C6386. Here is a link to the Microsfot Learn: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c6386?view=msvc-170

Comment: The warning contains more information that Microsoft Learn page cannot convey. See that is has placeholders `buffer_name`, `size1` and `size2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the expression `triLength(copyBinary.triboolList)` by X:

```
triboolList = new tribool[X];
for (int i = 0; i < X; i++) {
    triboolList[i] = (const tribool)copyBinary.triboolList[i];
}
triboolList[X] = DELIM;
```

You can now plainly see the error: it is illegal to access an array of size X at index X, since the last valid index is X-1.

Comment: Thanks! After you used X instead of the triLength function, I could see that I forgot to add 1 in the line "triboolList = new tribool[X]". This should fix the Copy Constructor.

Comment: It works now! I can't express my gratitude with numbers